# How to communicate between AWS ECS containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, fargate, ecs

### Problem

How do ECS containers communicate between each others?

### Situation

I use docker compose ecs integration.
In AWS docker context, `docker compose up` did a deploy correctly.
But reverse proxy doesn't work correctly, maybe because of **communication with containers**.

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: {ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/{MY_IMAGE}
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  nodeapp:
    image: {ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/{MY_REACT_IMAGE}
    working_dir: /src
    command: sh -c "yarn install && yarn build && yarn start"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

MY nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        # proxy_pass http://nodeapp:3000/; // works only for local
        # proxy_pass http://nodeapp.{MY CLUSTER}.local:3000/; // doesn't work

    }
}
```

### My understandings

1. In the same ECS service, containers can communicate with each other by **localhost**.
2. In the diffrent ECS service, containers can communicate with each other by **service discovery**.

Are these correct? And, how do I do that?

##### 1: The same ECS service

I tried to do that at first. But, `docker compose up`(ecs integration) created different services(for *nginx service* and *application(react) service*. How do I configure that?

##### 2: The different service

In nginx conf, **proxy_pass http:nodeapp.{MY_CLUSTER}.local:3000** doesn't work correctly.

---

How do ECS containers communicate between each others?
Let me know the simplest way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Understanding 1 is not correct, localhost is only for internal containers not other can access on localhost, if they share same network name can be used, nodeapp:3000 will work on local.

For different services we have to call them by local IP or a domain name if not in same network.